# Android.mk to include libaudio.so for native compile

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk

I have a code written in Native . I want to access the Audio HAL through this native code. My native code is a media player kind of code. So what changes do I include in the Android.mk file so it includes the libaudio.so in its compilation. According to my understanding libaudio is infact the HAL for audio.

Comment: The supported API for Android audio is OpenSL.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/audio.html

http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/3180-compiling-libaudio-on-its-own/

Its way of compiling libaudio.so ,have a look at it. It gives you the way, especially the second link which contains recording FM music. The libaudio is problematical in the sense that it contains vendor specific functions which unfortunately are not decorated/exposed .The best bet is get libaudio standard from android git sourcetree , change the way u like things u want to expose and compile only libaudio

`make audio.primary.herring`

Then backup of ur current rom, turn phone off, replace original libaudio with yours and bingo u are good to go. this is what i have done in samsung galaxy case

Comment: Thanks you syed I ll try this and get back with my explorations.